# Converted Array from Array-list not being passed to SQlite Database Method on First Button Click

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I'm creating an android app that a user enters data through dynamically created editText. These editText are stored in a `List<EditText>` and is converted to a `List<String>` to get the values. These values in the `List<String>` is also converted to a `String array` and passed to a method in the database for results on Button click. Now the problem I'm facing is that I get my results when I click the button twice.

Here is the code for the Activity

```
InfoBase base;
Button add;
int count = 1;
LinearLayout platform;
TextView showT, arr, multiview;
EditText addEdits;
List<EditText> values = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> results;
List<String> frmEdit;
String[] transVal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_symptoms);
    showT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    base = new InfoBase(this, null, null, 1);
    arr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editArr1);
    multiview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.multiText);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butAdd);
    platform = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.base);
    add.setOnClickListener(generate);
    results=new ArrayList<>();
    frmEdit=new ArrayList<>();
}

View.OnClickListener generate = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            addEdits = new EditText(getSymptomsActivity.this);
            addEdits.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(400, 79));
            addEdits.setText("");
            platform.addView(addEdits);
            values.add(addEdits);
        }
    }
};

public void getIt(View v) {
    transVal = frmEdit.toArray(new String[frmEdit.size()]);

    for (EditText et : values) {
        String getVal = et.getText().toString();
        frmEdit.add(getVal);
    }
    results = base.getDiagnosis(transVal);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String details : results) {
        builder.append(details + "\n");
    }
    arr.setText(builder.toString());

    StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (String multi : frmEdit) {
        builder1.append(multi + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the method that the array must be passed to in the DB helper:

```
public  Cursor backwardSearch(String[] testVal){
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
     String query="SELECT S."+COLUMN_SYMP+", S."+COLUMN_SYM_ID+" AS _id FROM "+TABLE_LINKDS+
             " DS JOIN "+TABLE_SYMPTOMS+" S ON DS."+COLUMN_SYMPTOMS_ID+"= S."+COLUMN_SYM_ID+
             " JOIN "+TABLE_DISEASE+" D ON DS."+COLUMN_DISEASE_ID+"= D."+COLUMN_DS_ID+
             " WHERE D."+COLUMN_NAME+" IN ("+toArrayRep(testVal) +") ORDER BY S."+COLUMN_SYMP+"  ASC";
     Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query,null);
     return c;
 }

 public static String toArrayRep(String[] in) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            result.append(",");
        }
        result.append("'" + in[i] + "'");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

I tried to display the values from the dynamic edit-text which have been converted to `List<String>` in a textView and it displays when button is clicked once but the final result is gotten when button is clicked twice. I'm thinking the `List<String>` is not converted to a `String array` on first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the `frmEdit` list to an array before the list is populated. That is why you do not get results on first click. You need to convert the list to an array after it is populated by moving it after the for loop.

```
public void getIt(View v) {
    for (EditText et : values) {
        String getVal = et.getText().toString();
        frmEdit.add(getVal);
    }

    transVal = frmEdit.toArray(new String[frmEdit.size()]);
    results = base.getDiagnosis(transVal);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String details : results) {
        builder.append(details + "\n");
    }
    arr.setText(builder.toString());

    StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (String multi : frmEdit) {
        builder1.append(multi + "\n");
    }
}
```